# How to turn Google Keep Check List into Google Task List

Tags: google, google-keep, google-tasks

Before the advent of the updated Google Task feature I kept some to do lists in Google Keep, which supports a list of tasks and their check boxes.

Google Task lists have the advantage of allowing subtasks under a main task, something that Keep doesnt (to my knowledge).

Is there a quick way to covert those Keep Task lists into a new Google Task list?